# 2D Movement for 4 directions only working left/right

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have problem I want to make my player move in 4 directions: UP,DOWN,LEFT AND RIGHT ... here is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovingPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

float speed = 4f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);    
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);   
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.Translate(-Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);  
    }
  }
}
```

And it is working just for left and right , not up and down !?

Comment: Vector2.forward doesn't exist for 2d mode ...

Comment: what could be the "_fourth direction_" in this three.dimensional-space world... time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it moves the object relating to the global coordinates:

```
(...)
else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate(0, Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.Translate(0, -Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

Comment: I get this error : The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Transform.Translate(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses `else if` for all four directions. This means that the character can only move in one direction at a time. If 'A' is pressed, then all of the `else` branches are ignored. If 'D' is pressed the 'W' and 'S' branches are ignored.

It makes sense to use `else if` when swapping between left and right, or between up and down, since the player should only be able to move one direction on a given axis at a time. But the horizontal and vertical sections should be independent if conditions:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);    
}
else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
    transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);   
}

if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
    transform.Translate(-Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);  
}
```

I would also recommend looking at the [Input](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) class in the unity documentation. The input manager allows you to define input axes (based on keyboard, mouse, or joystick input), and read them as a continuous value on the range [-1, 1]. Unity defines two default axes called "Horizontal" and "Vertical" which read input from AD and WS respectively. To use virtual axes, you can use:

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: This doesn't help ... My y value changes but player still stay in center of screen .

Comment: If the y value of the character changes, but the apparent position on screen does not, the problem is from somewhere other than this part of your code. Either the camera position is changing to follow the player's y position, or (if the player is a rigidbody) its y position might be locked.

Is this in 2D or 3D? In 3D the problem might be that you are moving the player on the XY plane but the camera is looking at the XZ plane. Try using Vector2.forward instead of Vector2.up.

Comment: 2D objects can still be moved on the Z axis, and being in the 2D project mode doesn't disable 3D object creation or movement, so it can't hurt to check. Otherwise you'll just have to check if the camera is being moved. If you place a single static sprite somewhere, does the player object move relative to it?

Comment: Please check rigidbody2d of your sprite maybe gravity affect (Your object mass or gravity force maybe too high). If you don't use rigidbody2d maybe your objects transforms on z axis.